How do I fix this 5-bit boundary based union in C?
I have a system which expects a little endian 16-bit color value with three colors of 5 bit each and one alpha bit.
In big endian it looks like this:
R:{00000-11111} G:{00000-11111} B:{00000-11111} A:{0-1}
I tried to model that with
typedef union {
    
    struct {
        SceUChar8 R;
        SceUChar8 G;
        SceUChar8 B;
        SceUChar8 A;
    }  components;
    
    SceUInt32 Value;
} mgpColor8888;
    
    
typedef union {
    
    struct {
        SceUChar8 R: 5;
        SceUChar8 G: 5;
        SceUChar8 B: 5;
        SceUChar8 A: 1;
    }  components;
    
    SceUShort16 Value;
} mgpColor5555;


But the mgp5555 is somehow bugged as a I need the union to create a 16-bit type.
typedef union {

    struct {
    
    >>5 bits<< R: 5;
    >>5 bits<< G: 5;
    >>5 bits <<B: 5;
    >>1 bits << A: 1;
    }  components;
    
    SceUShort16 Value;
    } mgpColor5555; 

I've hit a brick wall.
The code blow works since I set up the 16-bit value manually instead of using unions like I want to:
SceUShort16 gen5551( SceUChar8  R, SceUChar8  G, SceUChar8  B, SceUChar8  A) {
    
     mgpColor5555 val;
     R >>=3;
     G >>=3;
     B >>=3;
     A= (A >= 0x80) ? 0b01 : 0b00;
     SceUShort16 temp = ((A & 1) << 15) |((B & 0x1F) <<10 )  | ((G & 0x1F) << 5)| (R & 0x1F);
     val.Value = temp;
     return val.Value;
}

Why isn't union mgpColor5555 above working?

What did this code do that was different from what you expected? "it's obviously bugged" is not enough information for me to understand what went wrong here, and to me it looks correct up to the obligatory warning that bitfields are underspecified and cannot be relied on to match an external data layout requirement.

@zwol it's pretty much impossible to trace the output as i was seeing it but the cause of the bug on this system's kernel with the specific build of gcc I was using was causing undefined behavior.
The root of the bugged behavior is believed to be when usimg SceUChar8 on the mgp5555 union instead of SceUShort16

SceUChar8 is presumably an 8-bit type? What did you expect to be the effect of using it in this context, and what happened instead? Be excruciatingly specific. Edit hundreds of lines of debugging spew into your question if you need to.

It sounds like you want a specific bit pattern from your bit field, but C doesn't define how the bits are ordered. So the answer is: You can't. You need to continue using bit ops.

Why you can't set individual values? void set_green(SceUShort16 *color, SceUChar8 green) { *color &= ~(0x1F << 5); *color |= green << 5; } etc.

@zwol using 8-bit type adds up to 32-bit total and the "value" expects a 16-bit I was able to read from it succesfully despite the 32-bit alignment mess up when using 8-bit values but in order to set them i had to use the shift method manually. I think the reason it works now is because the compiler understand that the union struct forms an 16-bit value.
The output before that when i was using UCHAR8 is literally as random as it can be, and by that i mean i the output was complete garbage always

@dimich i can set them now, the fix was to use a USHORT16 on the 5551 union .
SceUShort16 gen5551( SceUChar8  R, SceUChar8  G, SceUChar8  B, SceUChar8 A, int useUnion) {
    useUnion = 1;
     mgpColor5551 val = { .components.R = R >> 3, .components.G = G >> 3,  .components.B = B >> 3, .components.A = ((A >= 0x80) ? 0b01 : 0b00) } ;
    if ( !useUnion) {
     R >>=3;
     G >>=3;
     B >>=3;
     A= (A >= 0x80) ? 0b01 : 0b00;
     SceUShort16 temp = ((A & 1) << 15) |((B & 0x1F) <<10 )  | ((G & 0x1F) << 5)| (R & 0x1F);
     val.Value = temp;
    }
     return val.Value;
}

Write your own wrappers and use bit operations.

@KamilCuk the function now has an argument to let the programmer chose if they want to use the union or the shift method

to let the programmer chose if they want to use the union or the shift method sounds like a maintance burden and code duplication. I prefer following convention that there is one way of doing a particular thing.

I edited the question, incorporating the expected layout information from your answer in the question. Roll back (or edit at will) if you are unhappy.


How do I fix this 5-bit boundary based union in C?

Bit fields are not portable. Use bit operations. Write your own wrappers, setters and getters, for accessing the 5-bit fields you want to get.
I would do something along:
struct { uint8_t R, G, B, A; } mgpColor8888;
struct { uint8_t R :5, G :5, B :5, A :1; } mgpColor5555;
#define mgpColor5555_INIT(R, G, B, A)  (struct mgpColor5555){ \
   R>>3, G>>3, B>>3, A>=0x80 }
uint16_t mgpColor5555_to_16(const struct mgpColor5555 *t) {
   return ((t->A & 1) << 15) |((t->B & 0x1F) <<10 )  | ((t->G & 0x1F) << 5)| (t->R & 0x1F);
}


While they are non-portable, they are designed exactly for the OP's purpose: Fit data into an externally imposed format. To this end, it is specified that the bit fields are adjacent; IIUC, the main issue are bit/byte order issues, to which code needs to cater which is aimed at more than one platform. But your suggestion is pointless: If you do the hand-packing, there is no need for the bit-fields any longer.

they are designed exactly for the OP's purpose Yes and no. They are designed to represent the structure of the machine you are programming on. So endianess, order of bits, is of the machine you are on. So if you are interfacing with DMA on little endian or big endian machine, the bitfield structure may be the same (assuming DMA layouts follows machine). In many cases ppl use bif fields to write interfaces to external devices that have the layout of bits given in datasheets unrelated to the architecture you are writing your program on. In such cases, you should use bit shifts.

there is no need for the bit-fields any longer. I agree, but in this case the assembly should look nice enough. For speed, I would consider removing bit-fields and maybe using uint_fast8_t, but I left the bit-fields in my answer. | Also, you may want to check https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n897.pdf page 64 and check https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html.

typedef union {

struct {

SceUShort16 R: 5;
SceUShort16 G: 5;
SceUShort16 B: 5;
SceUShort16 A: 1;
} components;

SceUShort16 Value;
} mgpColor5555;

This is working as expected. I was using UCHAR8 before this instead of USHORT16
I need to figure out the internals as to why this works and the UCHAR8 didn't. As i basically fixed it through brute force/trying different types
the system expects a little endian 16-bit color value.
in big endian it looks like this:
R:{00000-11111} G:{00000-11111} B:{00000-11111} A:{0-1}|

because you have different type here

The issue is likely that for the first bit field, the compiler "allocates" an object of the specified member type, which in your not-working example was an 8 bit int. It then fits successive bit field members in there until the object is full. Because your object only has 8 bits, the second member already does not fit; the compiler allocates a second char. Same for members 3 and 4, makes a 4 char = 32 bit struct. If you declare the members as 16 bit types, all bit fields fit into the first "allocated" object. The union should be superfluous (and, of course, was pointless before).

Per 6.7.2.1, paragraph 11 of the (draft) C11 standard: "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. ...

(cont) "The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified."  If you always want control over where the bits are in your variables, YOU CAN NOT USE BIT-FIELDS.
